# Infinite coproducts in Abelian categories.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I am currently (re)learning homological algebra: and I'm trying to do most proofs in a bit more general context of Abelian categories.

As far as I am aware, they are supposed to represent for the most parts: modules over a ring, so I was wondering if there is an analogous behavior when it comes to infinite coproducts. If we take an infinite coproduct over modules, we get basically the direct sum and along with it a notion of projections, since direct sums are actually a submodule of the product.

Assuming that an infinite coproduct exists in an Abelian category, is there a way of constructing these projections? Preferably with some universal properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $M_i$ $i\in I$ be a family of objects, and $\coprod_{i\in I} M_i$
be a coproduct. Let $i_0\in I$ and $I'=I-\{i_0\}$. Then there is a natural
isomorphism
$$M_{i_0}\amalg\left(\coprod_{i\in I'}\right) M_i\cong \coprod_{i\in I} M_i$$
by general categorical principles. In an Abelian category, finite
products and coproducts coincide, so we have a map
$$\coprod_{i\in I} M_i\to
M_{i_0}\amalg\left(\coprod_{i\in I'}\right)\cong M_{i_0}\oplus\left(\coprod_{i\in I'}\right) M_i\to M_{i_0}.$$

We can dualise this to get maps $M_{i_0}\to\prod_{i\in I}M_i$.